# Z-wave on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, zwave

Is there any module for using a Z-wave USB dongle on Raspbian?

I saw they had a [custom OS for z-wave on Pi](https://razberry.z-wave.me/), but I have other services running so I'd rather use a Debian based system.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like their [other USB device, the UZB](http://z-wave.me/index.php?id=28), has default Linux Drivers according to their documentation.  Maybe try that instead of the RaZberry?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Aeotec Z-Wave USB stick (Z-stick 7) with Rapsberry Pi4/Raspbian by using
[zwavejs2mqtt/](https://zwave-js.github.io/zwavejs2mqtt/#/) running as Docker container as gateway for HomeAssistant.